# Recreating google natural language entity display

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-nl

I've been playing around with google's entity analyser, and it looks really good!

But I've been bashing my head against this for a while - I'm trying to replicate the image below (seen on [google's natural language api page](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/))

[image]

This is the format of the entity data I get back from a request.

There's no order to the data, only occurrences - so looping through each word, and checking against the enities seems really slow, and as there's multiple of each word - it might get a little complicated.

```
[
  {
  "mentions": [
    {
      "text": { "content": "group", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "COMMON",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "group", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "COMMON",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "group", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "COMMON",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0.30000001192092896, "score":0.30000001192092896 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "group", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "COMMON",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0.30000001192092896, "score":-0.30000001192092896 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "group", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "COMMON",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "group", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "COMMON",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    } 
  ],
  "metadata": {},
  "name": "group",
  "type": "ORGANIZATION",
  "salience": 0.34768930077552795,
  "sentiment": { "magnitude": 1.100000023841858, "score": 0 }
},
{
  "mentions": [
    {
      "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "PROPER",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "PROPER",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "PROPER",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "PROPER",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "PROPER",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "PROPER",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "PROPER",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "PROPER",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "PROPER",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "PROPER",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0.10000000149011612, "score":-0.10000000149011612 }
    },
    {
      "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
      "type": "PROPER",
      "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
    },
  {
    "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
    "type": "PROPER",
    "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0.20000000298023224, "score": -0.20000000298023224 }
  },
  {
    "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
    "type": "PROPER",
    "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
  },
  {
    "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
    "type": "PROPER",
    "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
  },
  {
    "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
    "type": "PROPER",
    "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
  },
  {
    "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
    "type": "PROPER",
    "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
  },
  {
    "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
    "type": "PROPER",
    "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
  },
  {
    "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
    "type": "PROPER",
    "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
  },
  {
    "text": { "content": "Commonwealth", "beginOffset": -1 },
    "type": "PROPER",
    "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
  },
  {
    "text": { "content": "Commonwealth of Nations", "beginOffset": -1 },
    "type": "PROPER",
    "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
  },
  {
    "text": { "content": "Commonwealth\r\nOne", "beginOffset": -1 },
    "type": "PROPER",
    "sentiment": { "magnitude": 0, "score": 0 }
  }
],
"metadata": {
  "mid": "/m/0j7v_",
  "wikipedia_url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_of_Nations"
},
"name": "Commonwealth of Nations",
"type": "LOCATION",
"salience": 0.28001657128334045,
"sentiment": { "magnitude": 1.7000000476837158, "score": 0 }
 }, 
  ...
  ]
```

Is there an easy way of doing this, that I've completely missed?
Thanks for any insight/ideas.

Ollie

Answer (score 0):

I believe **[beginOffset](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/basics#syntactic_analysis_responses)** is what you need:

> beginOffset indicating the (zero-based) character offset within the given text where the sentence begins. Note that this offset is calculated using the passed encodingType.

It should work if you specify the [EncodingType](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/EncodingType) in the request.

> If EncodingType is not specified, encoding-dependent information (such as beginOffset) will be set at -1.